# Basic Cocoa Bindings: Toggle a boolean from menu in IB

Tags: cocoa, macos, interface-builder, cocoa-bindings

I'm just getting started with Cocoa Bindings and while I've read through much of the documentation, I'm still struggling to implement a basic feature, making me question wether I'm doing it wrong or perhaps it's just not possible via IB.

Goal:  Have a menu item called "Toggle visibility" toggle the state of a Boolean property in my application controller (AppController) called "visibility."  I think this should be possible completely through IB.

(Note:  CoreData is not in use here)

What I think needs to happen is I need to have an NSObjectController who's content outlet is set to my AppController class.  Then I think I need to use an Action Innvocation binding.  But here's where I run into trouble.

Should the Controller Key be selection?  Should the Model Key Path be the name of my Boolean Property?  What should Selector Name be?

Or do I need to setup a separate action method called "toggleVisibility" that I can bind to?  If I did, why wouldn't I just use standard target/action associations, rather than bindings?

Any input / direction appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Goal: Have a menu item called "Toggle visibility" toggle the state of a Boolean property in my application controller (AppController) called "visibility."

Your goal tells you why you are failing.

In your description of your goal, you say that you want to set this menu item up as a command, a verb, an imperative sentence—“toggle the visibility”. But [that's not the right title for the menu item](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/XHIGMenus/XHIGMenus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000356-TPXREF121).

Moreover, implementing a verb menu item with Bindings is inherently difficult because Bindings is the wrong tool for the job. Bindings is for exposing properties in your UI. It isn't for performing commands.

The correct title is supported by the correct Bindings-based solution.

The correct title of the menu item is, simply, “Visible”.

This alone should give you a hint as to how to proceed. Here's another: When the selection is visible, the menu item should have a check mark; when it is not visible, the menu item should have no mark.

You want to bind a property of the menu item to, ultimately, a Boolean property of your controller. Normally, this property of the menu item would be `state`, but for whatever reason, the binding for it is named `value`.

So, bind the `value` binding of the menu item to the Boolean property of your controller.

Comment: Appreciate the comments - those were not actually the names of the items - I was just trying to use generic names so as not confuse the issue.  Apparently I failed. :)

Comment: OK, so ignore my critique of your choice of menu item name. The solution remains the same: Bind the menu item's `value` to your controller's Boolean property.